# rigging of animal's legs

Tags: rigging, bones

I'm new of Blender but I'm learning fast. For modelling etc. everything is quite ok... a lot of informations can be found online and usually are quite small stuff such as a shortcut etc.

My problem comes with the rigging of an animal's leg. As long as I work with "humans" everything is ok. But animals have something different... while humans have a knee, animals have the leg that bends in two points [knee and heel].

While for humans you setup the IK chain from the heel for an animal I setup it from the paw [animals walk with the knee "high"].
But if I set up the IK chain from here I have two problems:
1. I can create a target just for the first bone that is part of the IK chain [in this case the one that goes from the paw to the heel] but not for the knee. This means that if I stretch the leg and then I compress it again I risk to bend the knee on the other side.
2. The IK chain works great with two bones, but if I add a third one the second and the third appear like "fused together" and the knee remains blocked.

Is there a way to sort this out? Probably is me that still ignore some stuff but I'm keeping this project as something that I can use to improve...

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

Thank you in advance
Bes

Comment: Yes pls attach a file: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ or some infographic pictures, that will help.

Comment: This is the file... I'm sorry if I didn't add before... I didn't know how to do.
Thank you!

[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=137" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/137/)

Comment: [This tutorial could help](http://cgcookie.com/blender/lessons/creating-a-stylized-dragon-part-7/)

Comment: Thank you A LOT! I didn't think that I could find a tutorial bettere than the once of youtube... but this actually IS better!!!